# Installing postgis in mac

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to install postgis in mac. But I am not sure if I should compile it from the source code or install the binary. When I tried to install the binary it says that I need to install postgresql 9.1 which I already have. What should I do? Are there any clear instructions for installing in mac

Comment: I've had issues with postGIS on mac as well (my local as a test environment)...sadly the solution was to install it on a linux server instead.

Comment: Installed everything from sources. Works fine.

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail here.  How did you install PostgreSQL, how did you try to install PostGIS, which packages, which package manager, which versions, where did you download it from, what instructions were given to you, what did you do, what were the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

When I run into trouble I usually install from source.  This gives the configuration and compilers a better chance to tailor everything to your computer.  You must have the development libraries for postgresql installed however to make this work with postgis.